# Root Partition not of the size of EBS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created one **OEL 6.6 Ec2 on AWS** in one of the Region.

And assigned

```
Root Partition 25GB (When first seen it was hinting 15G)
And other EBS for other purpose
```

When I did `lsblk` on it I found that

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  25G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  15G  0 part /
```

While I created one of the Amazon's preferred AMI like : Amazon Linux Image or Centos provided Community AMI's I found :

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  25G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  25G  0 part /
```

Can anyone please explain me what is wrong here. Are these Logical partitioning done by the AMI vendor's at the time of creation or is something wrong with my configurations on AWS itself? How can I overcome this as I need that AMI only?

Comment: If anyone doesn't have the answer for it. Please don't downvote without a proper feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Amazon Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html#CloudInit) contains a customized version of cloud-init, an open source application built by Canonical that is used to bootstrap Linux images in a cloud computing environment, such as Amazon EC2.

[Cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tools can detect if the root file system (/) size differs from the partition size and utilize the appropriate filesystem expansion tool (e.g. resize2fs for ext4) to match the partition size.

From [Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03 Release Notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/):

> Cloud-Init has been updated to the 0.7 series, adding a number of useful features. One example is dracut-modules-growroot, which automatically resizes your root filesystem on boot.

Suggested solution (by @Murtaza Kanchwala):

You need to install that following module via these steps :

```
wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/epel/6/x86_64/cloud-utils-growpart-0.27-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/6/x86_64/dracut-modules-growroot-0.20-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh cloud-utils-growpart-0.27-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh dracut-modules-growroot-0.20-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -qa kernel | sed 's/^kernel-//'  | xargs -I {} dracut -f /boot/initramfs-{}.img {}
growpart /dev/xvda 1
init 6 or Restart using Amazon's own console
```

Comment: So this means that the AMI's which I am using is having an older version of Cloud-Init?

Comment: But I checked on my OEL machine and it's saying cloud-init version is 0.7.1, I think the module you specified is not installed. Which is causing the Root not to grow as the size of the EBS. Right?

Comment: Yes, most probably. I guess that more 'conservative' distros don't wan't to do such thing as resizing the partition in the background without explicit users command.

Comment: Can you suggest me a workaround to do that. 

http://blog.backslasher.net/growroot-centos.html

I tried bootstrap script to install it. But it didn't worked. You can update your answer for the solution. Thanks

Comment: You should probably open a new question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) for that, there are better chances of getting optimal solution.

Comment: I have added a solution here and also added the Question to Server Fault. Thanks http://serverfault.com/questions/782447/root-partition-not-of-the-size-of-ebs/782448#782448